# Use Preg_replace to remove Double Quotes

Tags: php, date, preg-replace

I want to remove Double quotes by using preg_replace please help me out

for example :

```
$str = '{"start_date":"2011-01-01 09:00","end_date":"2011-01-01 10:00","text":"test","start":"2011-01-01 09:00","date":"2011-01-01 10:00","text":"test"}';
$str = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $str);
echo $str;
```

and the output is

> {start_date:"2011-01-01 09:00",end_date:"2011-01-01 10:00",text:"test",start:"2011-01-01 09:00",date:"2011-01-01 10:00",text:"test"}

what i want is

> {"start_date":2011-01-01 09:00,"end_date":2011-01-01 10:00,"text":test,start:"2011-01-01 09:00","date":2011-01-01 10:00,"text":test}

So Please If anyone can help me to this i will be Very Thank Full

Comment: But why do you want to do that with `json` value why don't you use `json_decode` instead of using `preg_replace`

Comment: Why do you want to remove the double quotes?...

Comment: You can get the strings without double-quotes using `json_decode` as mentioned above: `$str = json_decode($str)->start_date;`

Comment: i am Using CanvasJs Graphs And in That is that date format comes in Double quotes then it cant be able to Pick that date so i want the Json Format to come like

        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 26},
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 3), y: 38},
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 5), y: 43},

Comment: You need to call the ajax from within that function only. I'm sure using `preg_replace` is not the correct way to work around anyways check [this](https://regex101.com/r/mN9dF0/1) out

Comment: i want to pick the data from the mysql database. and there the date format is like  -> new Date(2012, 01, 01, 00, 02, 00) when it call in json format then it looks like {"x":"new Date(0000,00,00,00,00,30)","y":2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for your case:

```
$str = preg_replace('/:\"+([^"]+?)\"+/', ':$1', $str);
```